# Ordernar consulta mysql com INNER JOIN usando Group By

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, order-by, inner-join

Tenho a seguinte consulta `mysql`que tem finalidade de retornar os registros cadastrados na tabela `membro` e sua respectiva movimentação na tabela `movimento`. Um membro pode ter 1 ou muitos movimentos, porém a consulta deve trazer apenas a última movimentação com base na coluna `id` da tabela `movimento`.

```
select 
 * 
from    
 `movimento` m
inner join
 `membro` mb ON mb.id = m.id_membro
group by
  m.id_membro
order by
    m.id DESC;
```

A consulta atual não respeita a ordenação feita em `order by m.id DESC;`

Abaixo segue a estrutura da tabela `membro` e da tabela `movimento`:

```
Tabela membro
 id   nome
 1    João Dias
 2    Maria Souza
```

---

```
Tabela movimento
id   id_membro   data_movimento
1     1           2022-01-01
2     1           2022-02-01
3     1           2022-03-01
4     2           2021-03-01
5     2           2021-03-05
```

No caso acima por exemplo, o registro **João Dias** retorna o movimento do dia **01/01/2022**, sendo aguardado que retorne o movimento do dia 01/03/2022.

**Resultado atual**

```
id_membro   data_movimento   id   nome
1           2022-01-01       1    João Dias
2           2021-03-01       2    Maria Souza
```

**Resultado aguardado**

```
id_membro   data_movimento   id   nome
1           2022-03-01       1    João Dias
2           2021-03-05       2    Maria Souza
```

Qual seria a melhor forma para ordenar os registros da tabela `movimento`?

Comment: não pra fazer isso numa única query, pq o order deve ser feito **primeiro** na tabela de movimento para depois fazer o `join`, isso pode ser feito com uma subquery, mas para isso a tabela movimento precisa de uma primary key, na sua pergunta não mostra isso, não há uma primary key, como um valor unico, tipo um auto increment? senão vai precisar fazer um `where` com id+data

Comment: subselect no where ... m.data_movimento = (select max(m2.data_movimento from movimento m2 where m2.id_membro = m.id_membro)

Comment: @RicardoPontual, eu mudei a estrutura da tabela movimento incluindo um id auto increment e ainda assim não conseguir chegar na consulta esperada.

Comment: sim não vai mudar a query só pq tem esse campo :)  mas ele vai te ajudar a resolver a query, vou escrever um exemplo pra ajudar

Comment: @RicardoPontual, estou tentando fazer um subquery, porém não compreendo bem como usá-la. No momento está assim:

select 
 m.nome, mv.*
FROM
 `membro` as m
INNER JOIN
 (SELECT mv.data_movimento from `movimento` mv WHERE mv.id_membro = m.id ORDER BY mv.data_movimento DESC LIMIT 1) as mov
GROUP BY
 m.id;

Comment: veja minha resposta com o exemplo :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aqui uma ideia para resolver: É preciso pegar a último registro, seja fazendo um `ORDER BY` ou `MAX` no campo "data_movimento" ou "id". O "id" foi criado porque, ao fazer isso é preciso saber qual dos registros foi escolhido, e como o "id" é único, ele é o indicado para identificar o registro.

A *subquery* seria assim:

```
 SELECT MAX(id)
   FROM movimento
  GROUP BY (id_membro)
```

Isso vai retornar só os registros que precisamos, agora basta por isso como uma *subquery* da query principal com mais um detalhe: também ligar as duas pelo "id_membro", para o que resultado seja correto. A query fica assim:

```
select *
  from movimento m
 inner join membro mb ON mb.id = m.id_membro
 where m.id = (select max(m2.id)
                 from movimento m2
                where m2.id_membro = m.id_membro
                group by m2.id_membro);
```

De uma forma mais "descritiva" podemos dizer que a *query* retorna os registos com "id" igual a o que a subquery retorna, o seja, o último movimento por membro. Se precisar mudar a ordem, basta mudar a *subquery*, e ela sempre vai retornar o "id" do registro correto, a primeira *query* só faz o `join` com "membro" para retornar o nome :)

Pode ver funcionando aqui: [https://www.db-fiddle.com/](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2vRKKPhFkr8MfRApZV8MsH/0)

Comment: Consegui compreender e também resolveu a questão. Muito obrigado pela resposta :)